# Not able to boot Debian arm64 on Windows using Qemu

Tags: windows, boot, qemu, arm

I am running a Windows machine and I want to emulate a Debian OS with arm64 architecture. I downloaded an ISO file to setup a fresh VM. I used the following command:

```
qemu-system-arm.exe -cdrom debian-8.3.0-arm64-xfce-CD-1.iso -boot d -machine kzm
```

I also tried other machines, but the result remains the same:

```
Warning: Orphaned drive without device: id=ide1-cd0,file=debian-8.3.0-arm64-xfce-CD-1.iso,if=ide,bus=1,unit=0
qemu: fatal: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0x00004000

R00=00000000 R01=00000000 R02=00000000 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00000000 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=00000000 R14=00000000 R15=00004000
PSR=400001d3 -Z-- A svc32
s00=00000000 s01=00000000 d00=0000000000000000
s02=00000000 s03=00000000 d01=0000000000000000
s04=00000000 s05=00000000 d02=0000000000000000
s06=00000000 s07=00000000 d03=0000000000000000
s08=00000000 s09=00000000 d04=0000000000000000
s10=00000000 s11=00000000 d05=0000000000000000
s12=00000000 s13=00000000 d06=0000000000000000
s14=00000000 s15=00000000 d07=0000000000000000
s16=00000000 s17=00000000 d08=0000000000000000
s18=00000000 s19=00000000 d09=0000000000000000
s20=00000000 s21=00000000 d10=0000000000000000
s22=00000000 s23=00000000 d11=0000000000000000
s24=00000000 s25=00000000 d12=0000000000000000
s26=00000000 s27=00000000 d13=0000000000000000
s28=00000000 s29=00000000 d14=0000000000000000
s30=00000000 s31=00000000 d15=0000000000000000
FPSCR: 00000000

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

What does this error message mean and how can I boot an arm architecture on my windows pc correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, `qemu-system-arm` and `kzm` are both 32-bit.
You want `qemu-system-aarch64`, and probably `-m virt`.
Since this is a "generic" virtual platform, you need to specify amount of RAM (`-M 1024`) and processor model (`-cpu cortex-a57`) separately.

Secondly, unless you are booting a kernel directly, you will need some kind of firmware. If you don't care about persistent boot configuration, you can simply grab [this image](http://releases.linaro.org/components/kernel/uefi-linaro/15.11/release/qemu64/QEMU_EFI.fd) and add `-bios QEMU_EFI.fd` on the command line.

If you *do* want persistent boot configuration, grab the [other image](http://releases.linaro.org/components/kernel/uefi-linaro/15.11/release/qemu64/QEMU_EFI.img.gz), decompress it, create another empty 64MB file (call it `params.bin`) and add `-pflash QEMU_EFI.img -pflash params.bin` to the command line (**in that order**).

You are probably going to have to add a disk image somehow, but that bit is neither ARM nor firmware specific.

Oh, and the use of `-cdrom` and `-hdX` with `qemu-system-aarch64` did not exist for `-m virt` until QEMU 2.3-2.4 somewhere.

Comment: what does the error "qemu-system-aarch64.exe: -drive file=arm.img: drive with bus=0, unit=0 (index=0) exists" mean?