# Create Debian ARM image on Windows 10

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, virtualization, window, qemu

I want to create a Debian ARM image using QEMU on my Windows 10 machine.
I created my command using hints from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1035100/not-able-to-boot-debian-arm64-on-windows-using-qemu):

> qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt -m 16384 -cpu cortex-a72 -smp 4 -bios
> QEMU_EFI.fd -cdrom debian-11.4.0-arm64-netinst.iso

There is no error message, and there is nothing else. What do I missing? I expect a installer to come up to Debian ARM ISO.

EDIT: I've a code and I'd like to compile and run it. "boot an existing image" would be perfect, but I've only Debian arm iso. So, I need to create a bootable image and then boot it.

Comment: Do you want to *create a bootable image* or do you want to *boot an existing image*? There is a big difference, please edit your question accordingly to avoid confusion.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.